# what programming language required to develop linux O.S?

Tags: linux

I want to know, what programming language is required to develop Linux operating system?.
How to start and what are the required concepts ? I want to create my own O.S to my PC.

I have knowledge in `C` and `C#.NET` as basic Programmer.

Please suggest me the way.

Comment: I would not recommend [Pascal](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html). C++ (or C) are probably your best bets. You might also get some value from [Lions' Commentary on UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%27_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition,_with_Source_Code) and/or [The Unix Heritage Society](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl).

Comment: thank you..i have seen those links those are very helpfull for me as a beginer

Answer (score 5):

The Linux kernel itself is mainly written in C with machine specific parts in Assembler (machine boot-up code etc.)  For documentation easiest thing to do is have a look into the `Documentation` folder inside the kernel sources.

I don't know your experience with kernel developing but for a start you should have a basic grasp on OS principles, there are good books out there.  I'd suggest reading

- Andrew S. Tanenbaum: "Modern Operating Systems" for a broad overview of OS concepts
- Daniel P. Povet: "Understanding the Linux Kernel" for a good explanation on kernel concepts and to get a understanding how the Linux kernel basically works and implements things.

Also if you don't have experience you might want to start with something smaller than the Linux kernel.  One good project to look into (since it's explicitly aimed to teaching OS concepts) clearly would be [Minix](http://www.minix.org/) (which is written by Andrew S. Tanenbaum mentioned earlier).

Comment: thank you.. i will go through these books. I am beginner in linux kernel development so as you said i will start from MINIX.